# Centering a div using flex and position: absolute gives different results on Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I am looking for an explanation why the following code works differently in Chrome and Safari

Chrome centers the inner item both vertically and horizontally, whereas Safari doesn't.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #e2e2f2;
}

.flex-overlapping-item {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flex-container'>
    <div class='flex-overlapping-item'>
      <h3>Drag photo here</h3>
      <p>Photo must have 1000px x 1000px</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-overlapping-item drag-zone'>
      <div class='drag-zone-content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRyQLx

Comment: How do they look different, please clarify?

Comment: @Paulie_D Clarified. Is it not looking different for you?

Comment: No... **explain** how they look different.

Comment: @Paulie_D As edited in the question, in Safari you will find "Drag photo here" lying on the left middle area of the grey colored div. In Chrome, it is in vertical and horizontal center.

Comment: @Paulie_D imgur link http://imgur.com/a/I3DA6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Safari doesn't treat absolute positioned elements as the rest of the browsers do.

- [Flexbox Gets New Behavior for absolute-positioned Children (from 2016)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children)
- [Flexbox - Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

To center an absolute positioned element in Safari you need to use `transform: translate`

*Note, if it should be relative to its parent, the `flex-container`, the `flex-container` has to have a position other than `static`, so here I gave it `position: relative;`*

```css
.flex-container {
  position: relative;                /*  added  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #e2e2f2;
}

.flex-overlapping-item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;                         /*  added  */
  top: 50%;                          /*  added  */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);   /*  added  */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flex-container'>
    <div class='flex-overlapping-item'>
      <h3>Drag photo here</h3>
      <p>Photo must have 1000px x 1000px</p>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-overlapping-item drag-zone'>
      <div class='drag-zone-content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only issue is (in Chrome), when you use translate to center, things get to be blurry :(

Know bug from 2016 (if I remember correct) and still not fixed :(

Comment: @Graahf Well, since it works w/o `translate` in Chrome, only use it for Safari :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your version of Safari may not be recognizing `display: flex`.

Older versions of Safari may provide spotty support for flexbox, and full support was not offered until version 10.1 (released March 2017).

Try replacing `display: flex;` with the following:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/webNbq) that you can use to test with your version of Safari.